# Vestax PMC-07 Mixer PSU

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, negative-voltage

I'm trying to fix a Vestax PMC-07 Mixer and I'm puzzled by the schematics.
It is fed by a single +12V wall-wart switching adapter through a DC Jack.
Can this configuration really produce a negative 10V rail using this combination of a NJM-7910 for the negative and a NJM-7810 for the positive?[image: PSU Schematics]

The full service manual can be found here:
[VSS-PMC-07PRO.pdf](http://rasteri.com/w/images/2/27/VSS-PMC-07PRO.pdf)

Comment: For that to work it needs to be fed AC from a simple transformer. +12Vdc will not work.

Comment: The schematic you posted shows a 15 VAC input to two half-wave rectifiers producing the positive and negative supplies.  It wil not work when fed from an external DC supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture you took from the service manual clearly says the power supply input is 15 VAC, right next to the connector.

It can't work with a DC supply.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you.